# Powershell test-path throws error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to pass the file name as argument to powershell. When i was checking the condition with test-path it throws exception.

```
if ( Test-path -path $argv[0] ) {
&"$MsbuildBinPath\Msbuild.exe" $MSBuildFile "/t:BuildAll"  "$Logger" "$ErrorLogger" "/p:AllComponents=$argv[0]"
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) {
    Write-Host "It failed, send a mail"
}
```

I am trying to call it like follows

```
U:\Scripts>Powershell -file "U:\Scripts\Build.ps1" List.txt
```

It is throwing exception as follows

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At U:\Scripts\Build.ps1:37 char:29
+     if ( Test-path -path $argv[ <<<< 0] -IsValid ) {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo. There's no variable with that name - $argv,  change it to $args.

Comment: Oh.. what a silly mistake it is